# Generic object in Typescript

Tags: typescript

I created a `Dictionary<TValue>` on TypeScript, but it doesn't works like I want, unless that I use it like an array instead of object. It's my Dictionary class:

```
class Dictionary<TValue> {
    [index: string]: TValue;
}
```

So I can only use it like this:

```
var instanceOfDictionary: Dictionary<string> = ...;
console.log(instanceOfDictionary["test"]);
```

But I would like use like:

```
console.log(instanceOfDictionary.test);
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible?

Not unless you explicitly add `test` as a member. So, no.

Comment: Really, I think that if I turn it in a class that allow this member will better for me, are limited number of member (about 10), so I think that it'll be better than I use "undefined" members. Thanks.